# Infinite loop (on purpose) using puppeteer cluster

Tags: javascript, for-loop, puppeteer, infinite-loop, puppeteer-cluster

I am very new to puppeteer-cluster. My goal is to scrape a list of 100 sites infinitely, so once I get to the 100th link, script would start over again (Ideally reusing the same cluster instance). Is there a better way, or proper way to do this? I was thinking it could be easier to just have an infinite loop (and rotate elements), on purpose. Any advice would be appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
(async () => {
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
        maxConcurrency: 20,
        monitor: true
    });

    // Extracts document.title of the crawled pages
    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
        const pageTitle = await page.evaluate(() => document.title);
        console.log(pageTitle);
    });

    // In case of problems, log them
    cluster.on('taskerror', (err, data) => {
        console.log(`  Error crawling ${data}: ${err.message}`);
    });

    while (true) {
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(crawl, 5000));
    }

    async function crawl() {
        for (let i = 0; i < sites.length; i++) {
            const site = sites[i];

            site["product_urls"].forEach(async (url) => {
                await cluster.execute(url);
            });
        }

        await cluster.idle();
    }
})();
```

Comment: I think this is better suited for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That being said, just check if i is equal to sites.length - 1 and run `crawl()` again?, no need to run a setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (;;) {}
```

Will give you an infinite loop without running in to any issues from things like ESLint, or warnings about "unreachable code".

That said, it might not hurt to put a fallback condition so that your code is able to end safely if needed